# Defining an array of a set size in header file

Tags: c

I want to define a pointer to an character array of a set value in a header file.
Essentially - I want to declare a chessboard in a header file.

Would something like this work, or should I be using #define?
Thank you.

```
#ifndef myHeader
#define myHeader

typedef *char[8][8] Chessboard;

#endif
```

EDIT:

I have to admit I'm practicing for an upcoming test and this is just an old assignment (from one of the previous tests).
After some thought and study on how header files behave, I've found that

```
char array[8][8]; 
char*** Chessboard = (char***) malloc (sizeof (char**)); 
*(Chessboard) = array;
```

could work - however, I'm supposed to declare a type, and don't know how to do this.

To clarify - I want to define a type "Chessboard", that is a pointer to an 8x8 array.

Comment: Why the pointer? I suggest `typedef char[8][8] Chessboard;` Or better, `#define` the dimensions since some chess board problems use a non-standard board, and so you don't confuse these `8`s with any other magic `8`s. For example there are usually 8 bits in a byte, and there are 8 pawns. Now, suppose at some later time you want to change the size of the board, or the number of pawns. You will have a tough time combing through the code deciding *which* `8`s need to be changed, so please avoid magic numbers.

Comment: Do you want to declare a _type_ or a _variable_?  `typedef` is for _types_.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `extern char Chessboard[8][8];`, if you want to make a global `Chessboard` variable.

Comment: `typedef char (*Chessboard)[8][8];` ?

Comment: @AndrewSun has the right idea imo. In my experience getting fancy will hurt you more than help. just declare an extern global variable in the header file and comment it as a global and you should be good to go.

Comment: @AndrewSun Post that as an answer.

Comment: I have to admit I'm practicing for an upcoming test and this is just an old assignment (from one of the previous tests).

After some thought and study on how header files behave, I've found that
`char array[8][8];
char*** Chessboard = (char***)  malloc (sizeof (char**));
*(Chessboard) = array;
`
could work - however, I'm supposed to declare a _type_...

Comment: @VidStropnik no that will not work at all

Comment: To clarify - I want to define a type "Chessboard", that is a pointer to an 8x8 array.

Comment: Now you unclarified it again, since `char*** Chessboard` in the previous comment is a variable, not a type. What's the problem with suggestions by Weather Vane, Andrew Sun and BLUEPIXY? "Thought and study on how header files behave" makes me think you don't understand how header files behave. They don't "behave", they are just pasted in place by the preprocessor wherever you `#include` them. That's why a header file needs to mark variables at `extern`, while the actual variable definition has to sit in a .c file. Otherwise you will have a new static "instance" of your variable in each .c file.

Comment: Yes, I understand this (how header files work) now, but I did not at the strat.

Weather Vane's suggestion doesn't declare a pointer to an array, rather just an array.

It is unclear to me if Andrew Sun's suggestion defines a type. I know my edit doesn't to that either, but this is something I want to do.

BLUEPIXY's option seems the best out of the bunch - If I understand his code correctly, that is.

Comment: @WeatherVane `typedef char[8][8] Chessboard;` -->  `typedef char Chessboard[8][8];`

Comment: Andrew Suns suggestion doesnt define a type, but then you really dont need a type. Just make a honking big global variable called ChessBoard as he suggests

Answer (score 2):

> I want to define a type "Chessboard", that is a pointer to an 8x8 array.

```
// .h
typedef char (*Chessboard_T)[8][8];
extern Chessboard_T Chessboard_Var;

// .c
static char board[8][8];
Chessboard_T Chessboard_Var = &board;

// Usage example
void foo() {
   (*Chessboard_Var)[0][4] = 'K';
}
```

Hiding pointers in typedefs is usually frown upon.

---

A more common solution to capture the state would employ `Chessboard` as a structure.  Example:

```
// Chessboard.h
typedef struct {
  char board[8][8];
  unsigned move_count;
  int en_pass;
  int castle;
  int *history;
  // etc.
} Chessboard;

// Various functions that operate with a Chessboard
Chessboard *Chessboard_Create(void);
Chessboard_Destroy(Chessboard *cb);
Chessboard_This(..);  
Chessboard_That(..);
...
```