# Typedef a pointer to 2D array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, typedef

I need to declare a type (with typedef), that's a char pointer to a 2D array.

```
typedef char* board {
    char* arr[8][8];
}chessboard;
```

But it won't compile. I found this too :

```
typedef char board[8][8];
```

This works, but it's not actually a pointer to an array.
I'd appreciate any ideas, thank you.

Comment: what is `char*` after `typedef`?

Comment: do you want `struct` instead?

Comment: `typedef char board[8][8];` --> `typedef char (*board)[8][8];` (use `(*board)[r][c]`) or `typedef char (*board)[8];` (use `board[r][c]`)

Comment: I'm not sure. The instructions in this exercise say I need to declare a type chessboard which is a pointer to a 2d array of 8 rows and 8 columns. Should that then be a struct?

Comment: `typedef`ing pointers is generally a bad idea that is error-prone and makes code unclear....

Comment: "*char pointer to a 2D array.*" a pointer either points to a `char` ***or*** to an array (of which ever type). A pointer cannot point to two different variables both a the same time.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45851017/971127)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thank you this is very useful!

Comment: @alk I'm sorry, I meant pointer to 2D char array.

Comment: @DavidBowling Okay, I'll try it another way then.
Thank you!

Comment: @MasaEgart-- if the assignment says to use `typedef` to define a type that is a pointer to an array, that is what you should do; I was just commenting that this is rarely the right thing to do in actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing

```
typedef char (*BoardPointer)[8][8]
```

defines `BoardPointer` as a type pointing to an 8x8 array of `char`, so

```
BoardPointer boardpointer;
```

defines `boardpointer` to be a pointer to a 8x8 array of `char`.

To allocate an array of 8x8 `char` you can then do:

```
BoardPointer boardpointer = malloc(sizeof *boardpointer);
if (NULL == boardpointer)
{
  perror("malloc() failed");
}
else
{
  // use boardpointer here. Set all elements to '\0' for example:
  for (size_t r = 0; r < 8)
  {
    for (size_t c = 0; c < 8)
    {
      (*boardpointer)[r][c] = '\0';
    }
  }

  free(boardpointer);
}
```

---

As others pointed out that `typedef`ing pointer is error-prone and makes code difficult to read you could alternatively do:

```
typedef char Board[8][8]

Board * boardpointer = malloc(sizeof *boardpointer);
if (NULL == boardpointer)
{
  perror("malloc() failed");
}
else
{
  // use board here. Set all elements to '\0' for example:
  for (size_t r = 0; r < 8)
  {
    for (size_t c = 0; c < 8)
    {
      (*boardpointer)[r][c] = '\0';
    }
  }

  free(boardpointer);
}
```

or just

```
typedef char Board[8][8]

Board board;
// use board here. Set all elements to '\0' for example:
for (size_t r = 0; r < 8)
{
  for (size_t c = 0; c < 8)
  {
    board[r][c] = '\0';
  }
}
```